# Adding to a vector in multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, design-patterns

I want to do a selection of point on certain conditions and put the selected points in a new container.

```
void IntervalMapEstimator::extract_relevant_points_multithread(std::vector<Point3D>&  relevant_points ,std::vector<Point3D>& pointcloud, doubleIE cell_min_angle_sensor_rot, doubleIE cell_max_angle_sensor_rot)
{
    relevant_points.reserve (pointcloud.size ());

#pragma omp parallel for shared (relevant_points, pointcloud, cell_min_angle_sensor_rot, cell_max_angle_sensor_rot) num_threads(5)
        for(int i = 0; i < pointcloud.size(); i++) {
           if( -- condition -- ){
#pragma omp critical(push_in_relevant_points)
                     relevant_points.push_back(pointcloud[i]);                     
            }
        }
}
```

So i have a multi thread environment working with openMp, the thing is, every time a point is selected by the condition i have to use my critical clause( which basically work like a std::lock_guard) to push the value to relevant_point container. So there is like bottleneck to use this container.

I'm searching for a way to go around the problem and get more efficiency, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Create a local vector which you push into and then merge those local arrays with the main vector once after your loop is done?

Comment: @MikeVine Post this as an answer

Comment: I'm not sure i understood what you said, but it sounds like the problem is the same. I will have to access the local vector with different threads.

Comment: @tony497 _local_ means _thread-local_, such that each thread has its own vector. You can achieve this, e.g., by declaring such vectors inside `#pragma omp parallel` section and then use just `#pragma omp for`.

Comment: You could try to use an other data structure built for concurrency, instead of `std::vector`.
For example, `tbb::concurrent_vector`: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506203.

Comment: Ok i think i get it! Thanks! I need to understand how to do it with openMp now. I will use the private clause for relevant_points, so each thread as is own vector but how to join them at the end  with openMp ?

Comment: @fwyzard I did try to use tbb at first, but i didn't manage to make it work on my project, so i'm working with openMp now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my solution, it doesn't work that well, only a fews microseconds earned in average on each iteration of the loop (my sample is about 15000 points).
Because in the end i still have stop the calculation to add the result of the local thread to my final vector.

```
void IntervalMapEstimator::extract_relevant_points_multithread_with_localvector(std::vector<Point3D>&  relevant_points ,std::vector<Point3D>& pointcloud, doubleIE cell_min_angle_sensor_rot, doubleIE cell_max_angle_sensor_rot)
{
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(5)
    {
        std::vector<Point3D> local_relevant_points;

        #pragma omp for
            for(int i = 0; i < pointcloud.size(); i++) {

                // Check whether the cell is between the 2nd and 3rd quadrant (--> e.g. -170 to 170°)
                if (cell_min_angle_sensor_rot < 0 && cell_max_angle_sensor_rot >= 0 && abs(cell_min_angle_sensor_rot) > M_PI/2 && abs(cell_max_angle_sensor_rot) > M_PI/2) {
                    // Point must be smaller than the minimum angle and bigger than the max angle (e.g. min-angle: -1.5 max-angle: 1.5 point angle bigger than 1.5 or smaller than -1.5)
                    if (pointcloud[i].pol_sensor_rot.phi <= cell_min_angle_sensor_rot || pointcloud[i].pol_sensor_rot.phi >= cell_max_angle_sensor_rot ) {
                        local_relevant_points.push_back(pointcloud[i]);
                    }
                } else {
                     if (pointcloud[i].pol_sensor_rot.phi >= cell_min_angle_sensor_rot && pointcloud[i].pol_sensor_rot.phi <= cell_max_angle_sensor_rot ) {
                         local_relevant_points.push_back(pointcloud[i]);
                     }
                }
            }

        #pragma omp critical
            {
                if(!local_relevant_points.empty())
                    relevant_points.insert (relevant_points.end (),local_relevant_points.begin (),local_relevant_points.end ());
            }
    }
}
```